# Ajax race conditions

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ajax

Is there a pattern or standard way to handle Ajax race conditions? Take the following example. You have two tables. Clicking a row on table 1 removes the data from DB and then updates table 2 (which would now be showing  all the rows of table 1 less the row that was clicked).

If someone where to click a bunch of rows in fast succession you could get a scenario where table 2 doesn't update for all the clicks do to timing/lag issues.

What might be a good way to approach this? I was thinking of using a possible queue but that kind of defeats the purpose of doing it asynchronously. However I would still have the benefit of the UI not locking.

Comment: AJAX and databases? How do the two come together in this?

Comment: yea i was kind of vague. Its a web app with data being sent/retrieved via ajax more specifically jQuery.get/post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a thought, perhaps you could create a list for your Ajax callback methods. You would wrap your actual Ajax callback in a method that adds that callback to a slot in an list.

This list waits for callbacks in a specific order and only executes if the top element (the callback you want called first) is filled.

Comment: Programmatically nesting the callbacks is a solid solution.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a race condition.

A race condition would occur when the behavior between two asynchronous threads becomes undefined. You can solve this problem by nesting the callback from the first call

Comment: Not all AJAX calls will complete at the same speed due to possible network hiccups.  We see it even in development on our local network, where a later AJAX call will finish before an earlier one, and the UI ends up wrong.  Nesting/queueing callbacks will solve it, but this **is** a race condition.

Comment: @Izkata This is incorrect, Javascript does not have race conditions because it runs on a single thread. The situation you're describing is akin to running two functions at the same time, one to open a file, and one to read the contents of the opened file. The file open function **must** run before the read function, but executing both at the same time means that sometimes the second function will run first. This is not a race condition, it's failing to order things properly. The correct answer for Javascript in 2017 is to use `Promise.then()` to run async callbacks in the correct order.

Comment: @DanielT. Incorrect with regards to ajax.  The network request runs asynchronously, _not_ inside the javascript thread, and can return in any order.  It is a race condition if you're relying on multiple requests to return in a specific order without controlling when they're fired off.

Comment: @Izkata It's not a race condition, it's an ordering issue. The request itself is handled natively by the browser, but the **callback** runs in the JS thread. Race conditions are caused when two threads running simultaneously share the same resource and read/write to the resource at the same time, leading to non-deterministic output. If you have two simultaneous AJAX requests, the output is deterministic; it's either the result of callback A, or callback B. What you don't know is the **order** that the callbacks will be invoked. This is no different than providing two buttons to the user and

Comment: not knowing which button the user will click on first. The result will either be the callback for button A, or the callback for button B, but never an unpredictable, non-deterministic output. If you need to control the **order** that callbacks are invoked in, then you need to use promises. But unpredictable callback invocation timing is not the same thing as race conditions.

Comment: @DanielT. That's akin to saying "threads that mess each other up due to altering shared memory isn't a race condition, because you can enforce deterministic behaviour with locks".  Race conditions are not restricted to threads; it's the name for when any uncontrolled concurrent behaviour can cause an unexpected result.  And simultaneous ajax requests _is_ concurrent behaviour.

Comment: @Izkata An 'unexpected result' in a race condition means that a function is non-deterministic, something that doesn't happen in JS because of exactly what you said: "when any concurrent behavior can cause an unexpected result". The keyword here is concurrent; AJAX requests are concurrent, the **callbacks** are not. Therefore, the result of callback functions in JS are **always** deterministic because they are executed sequentially, never concurrently. This post is a good read: https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/06/17/no-there-are-no-race-conditions-in-javascript/

Comment: @DanielT. That doesn't even touch on two requests triggered independently that can return independently and in any order due to network hiccups (and therefore hit the callbacks in any order), the whole point of this question and my comment.

Comment: @DanielT. I'd also note that the definition he quotes refutes his own argument, and he doesn't really explain why he's right in the general case other than "because".  Like you, he's conflating two different things, using one of them to claim neither is a race condition.

Comment: @Izkata It seems you have a misunderstanding of what a race condition is. Please have a read through the Wikipedia article, particularly the software examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition Once you understand it, you'll understand that one of the requirements for race conditions is **concurrent** execution, which AJAX callbacks are **not**. You're mis-using the term 'race condition' to mean "I don't know when the callback will be invoked", but under that definition, creating 2 buttons and not knowing when the user will click on either is also a 'race condition'. It's not.

Comment: @DanielT. Re-read the Networking section, then re-read this question.  It is _exactly_ what's going on here.

Comment: No, it is not. You are confusing network requests with the callbacks, equating them to be one and the same. Can you have a race condition with simultaneous network requests? Yes you can. Can you have a race condition with Javascript callbacks? **No, you cannot.**

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking callbacks are universal tool for dealing with async task's and indeed callbacks is the mechanism to handle AJAX requests in JavaScript. In the context of the callback you can even have reference to the row that is clicked(if closed in closure). You can find the following articles useful: [jQuery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [Using Deferreds in jQuery](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/)

One other thing that you should have in mind, if the user is allowed to click multiple buttons, is that multiple request will be started. However different browsers can handle different number of AJAX requests simultaneously: [concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse). To overcome this  you should implement some basic request queue.

Comment: +1 for being the only one talking about deferred stuff.